# I'm using Moovweb flex boxes but the sizes aren't working properly... what's happening?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, moovweb

My structure is as follows:

```
<div class="_flex_box">
    <div class="_flex_box_item_1">Stuff</div>
    <div class="_flex_box_item_1">Other Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Usually, this will split the divs side by side at 50% width each. But it's not working... anyone have any ideas? Basically, instead of being at 50% each it's like 70/30 or 60/40 for the different items.

The CSS looks as follows (I'm using Sass & Bourbon.io)

```
._flex_box {
  @include display-box;
  @include box-orient(horizontal);
  @include box-align(stretch);
  ._flex_box_item_1 {
    display: block;
    @include box-flex(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Those are the properties from the deprecated 2009 Flexbox draft.  Please do not use them without providing the standard properties as well:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

So I found an answer!

It seems it's something to do with the implementation of flex boxes, but I can work around it by setting the ._flex_box_item_1 width to 100%;

```
._flex_box {
  @include display-box;
  @include box-orient(horizontal);
  @include box-align(stretch);
  ._flex_box_item_1 {
    display: block;
    @include box-flex(1);
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This definitely isn't always necessary, but may work if you're experiencing this problem in your Moovweb project.

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying a width, flex items will take as much space as they need, and then the flex-grow and flex-shrink properties determine their final width.  If one item needs 70% and the other only needs 30%, then that's the amount of space they'll take up.

If you want your flex items to be a specific percentage of its flex container, you have to specify it.

```
.flex-item {
  width: 50%; // works with either Flexbox
  box-flex: 1; // deprecated Flexbox
  flex: 1 1 50%; // standard Flexbox
}
```